# Nuxt 3 + Primevue's Dropdown: Arrow Keys not working

Tags: nuxt.js, primevue, nuxt3

I have two Nuxt 3 projects where the PrimeVue Dropdowns do not work properly when using the arrow keys:

#### Expected behaviour:

When focused, the dropdown should scroll through its values when I use the arrow keys.

It works as intended [on the primevue demo page](https://primevue.org/dropdown/)

[image]

#### Actual behaviour

The dropdown opens, but the arrow keys control the internal scrollbar of the dropdown. The focus stays on the arrow symbol:

[image]

I am not sure if this is a Nuxt oder Primevue problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, I found the culprit. **In my nuxtConfig the theme was missing**. Once I added it, it works as intended:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: [
    'primevue/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css',
    'primevue/resources/primevue.css',
    'primeicons/primeicons.css',
    'primeflex/primeflex.css'
  ],
  build: {
    transpile: ['primevue']
  },
  ssr: false
})
```

The reason the theme was missing there is because I was importing it like this in my app.vue so I thought I did not need it in my nuxtConfig:

```
<link id="theme-link" rel="stylesheet" href="/theme/arya-blue/theme.css"/>
```

And the only reason I import it like this is because it allows me to easily switch themes...

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same thing using their [example project](https://github.com/primefaces/primevue-examples/tree/main/nuxt3-quickstart).
I added the code for dropdown component into app.vue.

```
<template>
    <div class="card flex justify-content-center">
        <Dropdown v-model="selectedCity" :options="cities" optionLabel="name" placeholder="Select a City" class="w-full md:w-14rem" />
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const selectedCity = ref();
const cities = ref([
    { name: 'New York', code: 'NY' },
    { name: 'Rome', code: 'RM' },
    { name: 'London', code: 'LDN' },
    { name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST' },
    { name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS' }
]);
</script>
```

Plus, I added Dropdown component into plugins/primevue.ts

```
nuxtApp.vueApp.component('Dropdown', Dropdown)
```

For me this worked. I didn't detect any problems with arrow keys on Firefox or Edge

Comment: You are right. I tried this example in my app and it does not work. There must be something different about my project 